# Function takes in two strings, want to compare nth character

Tags: c

I have a function that takes in two strings, and I want to, let's say compare the 2nd letter of each string to the other.
How do I fix this statement:

```
if (strncmp(str1 + 1, str2 + 1) != 0) {
...
```

I get an error stating that passing the argument makes a pointer from an integer without a cast.

Comment: That's not a proper use of `strncmp`, btw. There's a third argument `size_t n` which dictates what length you should compare up to. In this case, you can simply compare the characters themselves using `==`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to put "1" as the third argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (str1[1] == str2[1]) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

Comment: this would be the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the possibility that any of the strings can be smaller than the position you want to compare:

```
/* Return 1 if s1[n] > s2[n], 0 if s1[n] == s2[n], -1 if s1[n] < s2[n].
   Return -2 if any of the strings is smaller than n bytes long. */
int compare_nth(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i < n; ++i)
        if (s1[i] == 0 || s2[i] == 0)
            return -2;

    if (s1[n] < s2[n])
        return -1;
    else if (s1[n] > s2[n])
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Then, to do something when the `n`th characters are equal, you can do:

```
if (compare_nth(s1, s2, n) == 0) {
    /* do whatever you want to do here */
}
```

If you know for sure that there are at least `n` characters in each of the strings, you can just do what others said:

```
if (s1[n] == s2[n]) {
    /* do whatever you want to do here */
}
```

(Note: since indexing in C is from 0, `n` is used in the same sense here.  So, to test the second characters, `n` would be `1`.)